# Is there some way I can update the statistics on my SQL Server 2012 database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I don't have the management studio installed and cannot install the express version as there seems to be a problem with my computer set up.

However I have VS2013 and I can open up query windows.

I created Indexes but then since then I have added a lot of new data. Is there some way I can update statistics for my SQL Server 2012 database from the SQL Script command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try EXEC SP_updatestats to update all database statistics.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the SQL command line using the tool sqlcmd that is installed as part of SQL 2012.

Here's a link to the update statistics command that you'll need to put together and execute.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx

You can always create a script for the update statistics command, then execute that.

If you have both SQL and SQL Express installed, please make sure that you are connecting to the correct instance of SQL Server.  the machine name alone or localhost should take you to the full sql 2012, (the default instance name for this is MSSQLSERVER) and the SQL Express should have an instance name of SQLEXPRESS (if I remember correctly)  you'll need to use the naming convention  server\instance to make the connection (you probably knew this bit already)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
EXEC sp_updatestats;
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx)